# Keyboard isn't responding with expo start

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have an app with some `TextInput` on a screen. I had to do changes on a component which doesn't affect the layout of this screen nor those `TextInput` in any ways. For what I can say, everything worked fine until then but now if I'm taping a `TextInput` the keyboard appears but it does not respond at all (like not at all). What I can't figure out is why this happens only on my real Android device when using `expo start`. On a virtual Android device it works just fine. It also works perfectly on both if I'm using `expo start --no-dev --minify`. Reverting the project back doesn't resolve the issue. Any clues on where or what I should investigate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me, looks like the expo **performance monitor** was causing all the trouble. Disabling it resolved the issue. Would be nice if someone knowing the why would take the time to educate me.

Comment: Omg I had the same issue. Disabling the perf overlay resolved it!